# A PHP quiz that calculate averages

Tags: php, average

I'm trying to make a quiz that will show the person who take it the average of the number of answer they got right. For example: if they have 2 right it would display 66%. Can someone please explain to me how I can do something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightblue">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;color:white"> Answer these Questions</h1>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px">
        <?php
        $numcorrect=0;
        // If the submit button has been pressed
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            // Check answer
            if($_POST['answer'] == 21) 
            {
            $numcorrect= ($numcorrect + 1); 
            }
            if($_POST['answer1'] == 46) 
            {
            $numcorrect= ($numcorrect + 1); 
            } 
            if($_POST['answer2'] == 2468)   
            {
            $numcorrect= ($numcorrect + 1); 
            }
            $average=$numcorrect/count ($numcorrect);
            echo "<h1>Your Average is {$_POST['$Average']}</h1>";
        }
        ?>
        <!-- Quiz Form -->
        <form method="post" action="questionassign1.php">
            <ol>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3><li>How old am I ?</li></h3>
                    <input name="answer" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    <h3><li>How old is my Mom?</li></h3>
                    <input name="answer1" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    <h3><li>What is my favorite number?</li></h3>
                    <input name="answer2" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ol>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Check answer" class="btn    btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to divide two numbers?

Comment: What sort of average are you looking for? There are principly three types of average, Mean Mode and Median . Each would potentially give you different answers and be calculated in different ways

Comment: `$numcorrect` divided by `$questions_asked` for example...

Comment: I'm asking if I got 2 out of 3 questions right, it would echo You got a 66% out of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$numcorrect = 0;

// If the submit button has been pressed
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Check answer
    if ($_POST['answer'] == 21) { {
            $numcorrect++;
        }
        if ($_POST['answer1'] == 46) {
            $numcorrect++;

        }
        if ($_POST['answer2'] == 2468) {
            $numcorrect++;
        }
        $average = ($numcorrect/3)*100;
        echo "<h1>Your Average is $average %</h1>";
    }

}
?>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$average=$numcorrect/count ($numcorrect);
echo "<h1>Your Average is ".$average."%</h1>";
```

You already calculated the average, so put it in the string with the `.` string concat operator. Additional hint: Check your code, what happens if I don't know any answer?

Comment: I want it to require an answer do I use error? do I use an array for that? How do I go about that